# Regex replace 'whole' decimal numbers not followed by a certain string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace "whole" decimal numbers not followed by `pt` with `M`.

For example, I need to replace `1`, `12`, and `36.7`, but not `45.63` in the following.

```
string exp = "y=tan^-1(45.63pt)+12sin(-36.7)";
```

I have already tried

```
string newExp = Regex.Replace(exp, @"(\d+\.?\d*)(?!pt)", "M");
```

and it gives

```
"y=tan^-M(M3pt)+Msin(-M)"
```

It does make sense to me why it works like this, but I need to get

```
"y=tan^-M(45.63pt)+Msin(-M)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the regex is that it is still matching a portion of the decimal value `45.63`, up to the second-to-last decimal digit.  One solution is to add a negative lookahead to the pattern to ensure that we only assert `(?!pt)` at the real end of every decimal value.  This version is working:

```cs
string exp = "y=tan^-1(45.63pt)+12sin(-36.7)";
string newExp = Regex.Replace(exp, @"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?![\d.])(?!pt)", "M");
Console.WriteLine(newExp);
```

This prints:

```
y=tan^-M(45.63pt)+Msin(-M)
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```
(               match and capture:
    \d+         one or more whole number digits
    (?:\.\d+)?  followed by an optional decimal component
)               stop capturing
(?![\d.])       not being followed by another digit or dot
(?!pt)          not followed by pt
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi there if you need the out put as

```
   "y=tan^-M(Mpt)+Msin(-M)"
```

then then newExp should be

```
   string newExp = Regex.Replace(exp, @"(\d+\.?\d*)", "M");
```

if output is

```
 "y=tan^-M(45.63pt)+Msin(-M)"
```

then newExp should be

```
 string newExp = Regex.Replace(exp, @"(\d+\.?\d*)(?![.\d]*pt), "M");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may assert the point in a string where there are no digits and dots directly followed by "pt":

```
\b(?![\d.]+pt)\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugqP0N/2)

---

- `\b` - Match a word-boundary.
- `(?![\d.]+pt)` - Negative lookahead for 1+ digits and dots followed by "pt".
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\.\d+` - A literal dot and 1+ digits.
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.

---

See the .NET [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f!%5b%5cd.%5d%2bpt%29%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f&i=y%3dtan%5e-1%2845.63pt%29%2b12sin%28-36.7%29&r=M)